# what is use of ViewGroup in getView method of baseadapter

Tags: android

i am implementing custom listview, i that i am using getView method with ViewGroup, but i do not know what is the exactly use of ViewGroup, can anybody explain me what is the use of ViewGroup, if you give an example then it will be the best

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
```

Comment: This parent is a refrence of our Listview or Gridview..

Answer (score 1):

From documentation [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

> Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the
>   data set. You can either create a View manually or inflate it from an
>   XML layout file. When the View is inflated, the parent View (GridView,
>   ListView...) will apply default layout parameters unless you use
>   inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) to specify a root view
>   and to prevent attachment to the root.

***parent*** - The parent that this view will eventually be attached to

Answer (score 0):

`ViewGroup` helps to hold multiple `Views` together.

E.g. You can consider `ViewGroup` as your Layout and `TextView` as the `View`.

That means your `ViewGroup` contains `View` as a `TextView`.

Comment: but at some time v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); we will also implement in that viewgroup is null

Comment: @user2107365 Yes this will do as your Layout is Consider as a ViewGroup.

Comment: @user2107365 your parent View e.g here ListView is consider as Default ViewGroup